# View newest note in long text field on a LIST

Tags: list, view

I'd like to have a long text field to enter notes in, but I only want to see the last 3 notes I have made in the field. I want to keep all content ever put in the field, and view it as needed but not by default.

Comment: What kind of list is this in?

Answer (score 2):

One thing that you can do is turn on versioning for the list. Then you can create a "Notes" column that is set to multiple lines of text and select Yes for "Append changes to existing text." If you don't want to show the notes in the list, then you can modify the view and deselect the Notes column.